# Ubuntu 14.04 system installation crashes on Thinkpad t440

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, lenovo, crash

I am trying an usb installation of Ubuntu 14.04 on my thinkpad t440 but when retrieving the files and installing them, it prompts the installer crashed and it cannot go further. What are the steps to get the system done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the same error before when installing Ubuntu on an old computer. The Ubuntu installer was hanging about halfway through when retrieving files. I tried replacing the hard drive with another hard drive, and after that the Ubuntu installer went all the way through the installation from start to finish without hanging, and after the installation was finished it rebooted successfully to Ubuntu.